# How do I prove that $f(n) = 0$ for all $n$ where $n$ is a positive integer?

Tags: functions

In particular, $f$ is defined such that $f(mn)=f(m)+f(n)$, where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers. Also $f(n)\ge 0$ for all $n$, $f(10)=0$, and $f(n)=0$ if $n$ ends in a $3$. Thank you.

Comment: Not true, define $f(n)=\sigma_2(n)-\sigma_5(n)$ where $\sigma_p(n)$ denotes the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$.

Comment: Please would you clarify your response? Thank you

Comment: Did's function has all the properties required in your question:  f(mn)=f(m)+f(n) because the number of 2s (or 5s) dividing mn is the number of 2s (or 5s) dividing m plus the number of 2s (or 5s) dividing n. Also f(10)=1-1=0 and if n ends in a 3 then it is not divisible by 2 or by 5, hence f(n)=0-0=0.

Comment: Oh, now the question has been changed by someone. The requirement $f(n)\geq 0$ wasn't there before.

Comment: @EmbarassedGuy Oops, that embarasses me - it means I need to corect my proof ...

Comment: Thank you. Did "not true" mean that actually f(n) wasn't always equal to 0?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Exactly, For Did's example one has e.g. f(2)=1 and f(5)=-1.

Comment: My apologies, thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: OP: Next time you modify crucially the text of a question while people are discussing it, at least mention the modification through a comment...

Answer (score 3):

- If $n\equiv 1\pmod{10}$ then $3n\equiv 3\pmod{10}$ and so $f(n)=f(3n)-f(3)=0$.
- If $n\equiv 7\pmod{10}$ then $3n\equiv 1\pmod{10}$ and so $f(n)=f(3n)-f(3)=0$.
- If $n\equiv 9\pmod{10}$ then $3n\equiv 7\pmod{10}$ and so $f(n)=f(3n)-f(3)=0$.

From $f(2)\ge 0$ and $f(5)\ge 0$ and $f(2)+f(5)=f(10)=0$, we obtain $f(2)=f(5)=0$.

Now let $n\in\Bbb N$ be arbitrary. Write $n=2^r5^su$ with $\gcd(u,10)=1$. Then $u\equiv 1,3,7,9\pmod{10}$ and hence $f(n)=rf(2)+sf(5)+f(u)=0$.